# Trying to call a JS function and getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the above uncaught syntax error, which I think leads me to my next error, which is

Uncaught ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined onclick

My function seems fairly straightforward and I'm not quite sure where the issue could lie:

```
 function addEvent(event, user){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/addEvent/',
        type: "POST",
        data: {event_id: event, profile: user},
        success: function(){
            $('hello').html("Yes");
        }
        error: function() {
            $('hello').html("No");
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a missing comma. Change it like this:

```
function addEvent(event, user){
  $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/addEvent/',
      type: "POST",
      data: {event_id: event, profile: user},
      success: function(){
          $('hello').html("Yes");
      },
      error: function() {
          $('hello').html("No");
      }
  });
}
```